# Singleton Access Private methods acces public methods

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I have created a single class but I'm having a little trouble accesing the public methods from the private ones. My example is this:

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

  function init() {

    function privateMethod(){
        publicMethod();
        //this.publicMethod() also doesn't work
    }

    privateMethod();

    return {

      publicMethod: function () {
        console.log( "The private method called me!" );
      }
    };
  };

  return {
    getInstance: function () {

      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = init();
      }

      return instance;
    }
  };
})();

var singleton = mySingleton.getInstance();
```

It seems that the scopes are completely different. Should I be creating a singleton in a different way?

Comment: Where is the private "method" called?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, just added it. Called within the init();

Comment: @DevinDixon can you provide sample how you want use this?

Comment: @Grundy I thought the example above was pretty stripped down to suite anyone's need. The case I am using is for action tracking on a page. I want all communication with the server to be private, but methods like get page height, browser type, etc to be public.

Answer (score 1):

So why you don't want use something like this:

```
var mySingleton = (function () {
    /*private methods*/

    return {
      /*public methods*/
    }
})();
```

if approached formally by your question you need to change your code like this

```
...
function init() {

    function privateMethod(){
        publicMethod();//OK
    }

    privateMethod();

    function publicMethod(){
        console.log( "The private method called me!" );
    }
    return {

        publicMethod: publicMethod

    };

};
...
```

Comment: Thats not a singleton. I only want once instance

Comment: `mySingleton` is one variable

Comment: The example you posted would be known as revealing module, different from singleton.

Comment: and what's the difference with your implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that additional `init` function. And you will have to access the public methods on the `instance`, i.e. the object which you had returned from `init`.

```
var mySingleton = (function () {
  var instance = null;
  function privateMethod(){
    instance.publicMethod();
  }

  return {
    getInstance: function () {
      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = {
          publicMethod: function () {
            console.log( "The private method called me!" );
          }
        };
        privateMethod();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  };
})();

var singleton = mySingleton.getInstance();
```